# WPF TextBox AcceptsReturn = True

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox

In WPF Application I have a textbox.

I set its `AcceptsReturn` Property to `true`.
So, I can enter data in multiple lines.

When user press enter in the textbox I want to check :

```
1) Is the cursor on the last line?
2) If cursor is on the last line then check if thatLine.Text = Nothing?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private void TextBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
     if (tb == null)
     {
        return;
     }

     string[] lines = tb.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
     if (tb.CaretIndex >= tb.Text.Length - lines.Last().Length)
     {
        // cursor is on last line

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines.Last()))
        {
           // cursor is on last line and line is empty
        }
     }
  }
```

ok is in c# but i don't know the vb syntax..

if you need a translation to vb: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ ;-)

Comment: I changed the sample code with the explicite types. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. It works. I changed new[] to new() using code converter and then added new String(). Now it works.