# Editable multiline combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue with editable combobox. I can get textbox PART_EditableTextBox and make it multiline by AcceptsReturn="True" and TextWrapping="Wrap".

The problem I have is that I cannot make it work like classic textbox for text operations.

For example key down does not navigate in text and instead just fire item selection even if there is just 1 item in my collection it effectively refresh to original value. Same for scroll bar.

I found that I can catch some events (previewkeydown on parent element/ PreviewMouseWheel)  and handle them to not reset value but still missing the text navigation(moving in text by arrows) or having scroll bar.

### Edit

I find solution.

Insted of using ComboBox I used ComboBoxEdit from DevExpress.
Now it gets quite easy since they have already implemented property to solve halve of my problems.

this.ComboBoxEdit.AllowSpinOnMouseWheel = false
this.ComboBoxEdit.AcceptsReturn = true;
this.ComboBoxEdit.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

Only problem left was text navigation by arrows.
I catched PreviewKeyDown from parent element and implemented this.

```
    private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is TextBox tx)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                EditingCommands.MoveUpByLine.Execute(null, tx);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                EditingCommands.MoveDownByLine.Execute(null, tx);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks duplicate. See below answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101847/wpf-textbox-acceptsreturn-true
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718190/if-set-to-true-acceptsreturn-disables-detection-of-key-return-in-a-multiline-te

Comment: Ty for reply but this is something different.  In my case I have combobox that should behave as multiline textbox when IsEditable = true. Right now i dont know how to navigate in text by arrows or use scrollbar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the plan seems like a bad idea.

There are fundamental mismatches between functionality an editable combobox gives and what you seem to require from a multiline textbox inside one.

For one, the arrows already have an inherent meaning to a combobox.  That's how you navigate the autocomplete list using keyboard.

An editable combobox is intended to do autocomplete as well as possibly add a new item.

Maybe you could have a textbox and a combobox. The user switches between these using a togglebutton or some such. Depending on whether they want to add new  or look up an existing item.

I think your best bet is likely to build your own usercontrol if you particularly need this to look similar to a combobox.

The editable part would be a textbox.

The list of possibles can be a listbox inside a popup or expander.

You could choose whether to use a togglebutton to show your popup like the combobox does, or not.

Add the functionality you need without the problems functionality inherent to a combobox control adds.

Comment: Thak you. In the end i found solution to my problem.  I will edit my question.